# Other causes for VB6 trappable error Path/File access error (Error 75)?

Tags: vb6

Apart from those listed by microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264531%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

```
10   DBEngine.CompactDatabase Dbpath, DbTempPath, "", dbEncrypt
20   Kill Dbpath
30   Name DbTempPath As DbPath
```

The above code operates day in day out in a lot of installations but then extremely rarely line 30 fails and I get a call that the database is missing.

Today for the first time I saw it happen myself and the error that was thrown:

Path/File access error (Error 75)

However I don't think that any of the listed causes apply in this situation.

When this happened at an installation today and I renamed the temp file and ran the code again and the error occurred again.

(I think it just might have something to do with a hardware issue as making a copy of the file took a very long time.)

Comment: In case the `Kill` statement is taking a long time, you could use `Name DbPath As DbOldPath`, `Name DbTempPath As DbPath`, `Kill DbOldPath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to say, but my guess would be that the problem is with your `KILL` statement not finishing before the `NAME` statement runs.  Its never been clear to me, but it seems that the Windows NT File System has the option of implementing some file operations (especially for large files) asynchronously, so that the `KILL` may not be completed by NTFS, even though VB6 thinks that it is and has moved on to the `NAME` statement.

Probably the best thing would be to put some check after the `KILL` to make sure that the file is actually gone, before starting the rename with `NAME`.

Comment: This is interesting. It seems like the only logical explanation for what's going on, thanks

Comment: Its certainly something that many programmers, not just VB6 ones, have had to overcome. Disk operations are much slower than program code so it's often worth writing a library of 'safe' disk operations that wait and check that they have completed succesfully before surrendering control to the next line of code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the problem occurs but you could add a workaround using a DoEvents call or writing a small procedure to wait for a second or three (or longer) to allow time for the disk to complete the deletion or Access to release the file.

A more advanced workaround would be to write a function to check if the file is available before calling the rename.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think I will do something like you suggest or perhaps as David has suggested in his comment under the question